# Password hashing using CryptoKit

Tags: swift, macos, security, encryption

I'm using ([CryptoKit)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cryptokit) to use AES-GCM to encrypt some data and authenticate it as well.

However, I was wondering how I would generate an AES-GCM key from a plain text password. Normally, you would use a `KDF` function for that, like PBKDF2.

In `CryptoKit`, there is a `HKDF` class which does about what I want: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cryptokit/hkdf

However, I am wondering what KDF algorithm the [DeriveKey](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cryptokit/hkdf/3565573-derivekey) function uses. Does it use PBKDF2? Does it use `bcrypt`? If so, how do I specify settings, or are the settings automatically  determined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HKDF is defined in [RFC5869](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5869). It is intended to generate keys from some cryptographically secure "keying material" (IKM). It is not intended for stretching a human-generated password. As discussed in section 4 Applications of HKDF:

> On the other hand, it is anticipated that some applications will not
> be able to use HKDF "as-is" due to specific operational requirements,
> or will be able to use it but without the full benefits of the
> scheme.  One significant example is the derivation of cryptographic
> keys from a source of low entropy, such as a user's password.  The
> extract step in HKDF can concentrate existing entropy but cannot
> amplify entropy.  In the case of password-based KDFs, a main goal is
> to slow down dictionary attacks using two ingredients: a salt value,
> and the intentional slowing of the key derivation computation.  HKDF
> naturally accommodates the use of salt; however, a slowing down
> mechanism is not part of this specification.  Applications interested
> in a password-based KDF should consider whether, for example, [PKCS5]
> meets their needs better than HKDF.

I don't believe that CryptoKit offers a PBKDF of any kind (PBKDF2, scrypt, bcrypt, argon2). It's a very limited framework (I have yet to find a situation where it was useful). You will likely need to continue to use CommonCrypto for this, or implement it yourself (or use something like CryptoSwift, which I believe implements several).

Comment: Ah ok. Thats unfortunate. Thank you for your detailed answer though!